# how is True and False are working on this code

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, while-loop

```
while True:
    user_input = input('> ').lower()
    if user_input == 'help':
        print("""start - to start the car
stop - to stop the car
quit - to exit
""")
    elif user_input == 'start':
        print('car started...Ready to go!')
    elif user_input == 'stop':
        print('car stopped...')
    elif user_input == 'quit':
        break
    else:
        print('I donn\'t understand that')
```

So this is a simple program. However, the additional task was:
from the code above we can understand if the user entered "start" a message will be printed on the screen saying "car started" and if the user enters the same thing again, the same message will keep appearing. however, the task was if the user entered "start" the second time it should appear a different message, For example "the car is already started".

So only the first time it should show "car started" and rest of the times it should show "car is already started". the code below will show the answer but I cannot understand the logic behind it.

```
started = False
while True:
    user_input = input('> ').lower()
    if user_input == 'help':
        print("""
        start - to start the car
        stop - to stop the car
        quit - to exit
        """)
    elif user_input == 'start':
        if started:
            print("car is already started!")
        else:
            started = True
            print('car started...')
    elif user_input == 'stop':
        if not started:
            print("car is already stopped")
        else:
            started = False
            print('car stopped...')
    elif user_input == 'quit':
        break
    else:
        print('I donn\'t understand that')
```

I do understand the while loop well but I don't understand the logic behind setting things to false and then true. How is the code being executed? How's the loop and if statements handling them?

code reference
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_uQrJ0TkZlc&ab_channel=ProgrammingwithMosh
while loops part

Comment: What do you think it _should_ do, such that what it's actually doing is different?

Comment: (the important thing to understand is that the code in `if started:` is run if `started` is `True`, whereas the code in the associated `else:` happens if `started` is `False`; the opposite for `if not started:`).

Comment: The program begins with the car stopped.  If the user enters "start", it checks to see if the car is stopped, and if so it starts the car, otherwise it prints a message that the car is already started.  Similarly if the user enters "stop", it checks to see if the car is started and if so it stops the car, otherwise it prints a message that the car is already stopped.

Answer (score 1):

I try to go step by step, look at the comments.

```
''' Set the variable started to False, this will indicate if the car is started or not.
    At the beginning it should be False, since we haven't started it. '''
started = False

''' While True means, we stuck inside this while loop FORVERER, so we will have to
   'break' out of it using the break statement. '''
while True:
    # Get the user input, and convert to lower case
    user_input = input('> ').lower()

    if user_input == 'help':
        ''' If user input was 'help', print the help, and then jump to the begining of the
            while loop. '''
        print("""
        start - to start the car
        stop - to stop the car
        quit - to exit
        """)
    elif user_input == 'start':
        ''' If the input was 'start', we go into this branch '''
        if started:
            ''' If started is True (note, initially it was false), we already started the car.
                Just print, and start the loop again. '''
            print("car is already started!")
        else:
            ''' Else (started is False), we set it to True, indicating that we started the car,
                and print that we started it. Then start the loop again. '''
            started = True
            print('car started...')
    elif user_input == 'stop':
        ''' The input is 'stop', so we go into this branch '''
        if not started: # Equivalent to 'if started == False'
            ''' We try to stop the car, but started is already false, so we can't stop twice. '''
            print("car is already stopped")
        else:
            ''' If started wasn't false, than it is true, and this is a logical crap.
                BUT, we are here since started was True, so we set it to False, and print that
                we stopped the car. '''
            started = False
            print('car stopped...')
    elif user_input == 'quit':
        ''' User input was quit, so this is our exit point from this infinite 'while True' loop. '''
        break
    else:
        ''' We had no idea what was the input, print this message, and start the loop again. '''
        print('I donn\'t understand that')
```

Comment: so since we have set the value of started to true.
it will not print the if statement segment because its false so it will ignore it.
on the else segment we have set it to true so this time its execute the else segment

since the value of started is true now it will keep on execute the if segment and will ignore the else segment on the next loop am I correct?

Comment: Yes, but we start with False, not True as you wrote. So if we only deal with the if user_input = 'start' part, there could be 2 possible outcomes based on if we have started before, or not. For the first time, started is false, we ignore the if started branch, take the else branch, and now we start the car (set True). And for the next time we come here, and the started is True, since we just started it and not stopped yet, so we take the if started branch, and ignore the else branch.

Comment: @Marz Just don't overhink it. Your car can be in two states. Started, or not. That's all. If you try to start the car, you must check if it is already started, or not. If started, you can't start again, if not started, you start it.. You don't care about how you got there, don't care about the future... The only thing at that point what you are interested is if it is started already, or not, and if not, you start it. That's all.

Comment: yuh sorry I meant start with False. perfect that's exactly what I wanted thanx. I know am overthinking with small things but I just cant go over to the next step if I don't understand it. I believe I need to understand everything so I can be a good programmer later on.

Answer (score 0):

So Marz,

Your first program has only one set of check around user input ie if else works only based on user input. To take into consideration the state of car ie is it started or stopped we need another variable. So comes 'started' variable into picture. In your second program code the message is displayed checking both - user input and condition/state of car.
Hope that makes sense.